# Action methods in refluxjs

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, refluxjs

I am trying to learn `refluxjs` right now but looking at a github project called react-news.

Specifically this line of the project is a bit confusing to me:

https://github.com/echenley/react-news/blob/master/src/js/App.jsx#L80

`Actions.hideModal();`

`Actions` comes from `import Actions from './actions/Actions';` of the project.

When I look into `Actions.js`, the only instances of `hideModal` I see are on lines 41 and 50.

https://github.com/echenley/react-news/blob/master/src/js/actions/Actions.js#L41
https://github.com/echenley/react-news/blob/master/src/js/actions/Actions.js#L50

I am not sure where the logic for `Actions.hideModal();` comes from.

Answer (score 1):

In Reflux.js (at least in =< 0.2.x), actions are handled in stores. Once you go looking around in the stores, you'll see there's a `modalStore` which sets up listening to all actions, and triggers a propogation of the `modalState.show` prop when `hideModal` is called:

```
hideModal() {
    modalState.show = false;
    this.trigger(modalState);
}
```

https://github.com/echenley/react-news/blob/master/src/js/stores/ModalStore.js